# Search for file and download it (curl,grep,wget?)

Tags: linux, grep, wget, curl, jenkins

i am trying to setup a command with curl and grep that lets me search for a specific pattern on a website and downloads the target link.

i have tried countless ways with curl wget and whatnot but couldnt find a solution. my researches werent particulary helpful aswell.

so what i am trying to do is:

search a website (http://ci.athion.net/job/FastAsyncWorldEdit/lastStableBuild/)
for every file starting with "FastAsyncWorldEdit-bukkit-" and ending with ".jar"
and then save it as whatever.jar

The tutorials i found seem to not work on jenkins

thank you for any help!

Comment: How do you want to save *every* such file as `whatever.jar`?

Comment: sorry for being unclear on this, like user199239 already figured there is only one file fitting the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see correctly, on the page is just one jar file fitting your criteria.

Here is a nasty one liner, that does the job.

```
wget -c $(curl -s http://ci.athion.net/job/FastAsyncWorldEdit/lastStableBuild/ | tr '=' '\n' | grep FastAsyncWorldEdit-bukkit- | awk -F '"' '{ printf "http://ci.athion.net/job/FastAsyncWorldEdit/lastStableBuild/" $2"\n"}' | grep 'jar$')
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i was trying to accomplish

Comment: O well, any chance you can explain to me whats going on here?

because im kinda confused now why this works but this:  


`wget $(curl http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful?branch=master | tr '=' '\n' | grep worldedit-bukkit | awk -F '"' '{ printf "http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful?branch=master" $2"\n"}' | grep 'jar$')`   wont?

Comment: i have this doing the job for me now but jesus christ i cant get any of that :/
curl -L --compressed `(curl --compressed "http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful?branch=master" 2> /dev/null | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | grep worldedit-bukkit | sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d')` > worldedit.jar 2>/dev/null

...i didnt put it in code because i didnt know how to escape the "`" already in there...

Answer (score 0):

There are permalinks on the release page, which might be simpler:
https://github.com/boy0001/FastAsyncWorldedit/releases/

Also, the awk concatenates the url with the found link, but the second page uses absolute paths, so you don't want to join them:

```
wget -c $(curl -s http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful?br‌​anch=master/ | tr '=' '\n' | grep worldedit-bukkit- | awk -F '"' '{ printf $2"\n"}' | grep 'jar$')
```